# Can't get basic example working with Bullet 3 (haxebullet port)

Tags: c++, bullet-physics, haxe

Example of my code:

```
var collisionConfiguration = new bullet.Bt.DefaultCollisionConfiguration();
var dispatcher = new bullet.Bt.CollisionDispatcher(collisionConfiguration);
var broadphase = new bullet.Bt.DbvtBroadphase();
var solver = new bullet.Bt.SequentialImpulseConstraintSolver();
var dynamicsWorld = new bullet.Bt.DiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher, broadphase, solver, collisionConfiguration);

var groundShape = new bullet.Bt.StaticPlaneShape(new bullet.Bt.Vector3(0, 1, 0), 1);
var groundTransform = new bullet.Bt.Transform();
groundTransform.setIdentity();
groundTransform.setOrigin(new bullet.Bt.Vector3(0, -1, 0));
var centerOfMassOffsetTransform = new bullet.Bt.Transform();
centerOfMassOffsetTransform.setIdentity();
var groundMotionState = new bullet.Bt.DefaultMotionState(groundTransform, centerOfMassOffsetTransform);

var groundRigidBodyCI = new bullet.Bt.RigidBodyConstructionInfo(0.01, groundMotionState, cast groundShape, new bullet.Bt.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
var groundRigidBody = new bullet.Bt.RigidBody(groundRigidBodyCI);
dynamicsWorld.addRigidBody(groundRigidBody);

var fallShape = new bullet.Bt.SphereShape(1);
var fallTransform = new bullet.Bt.Transform();
fallTransform.setIdentity();
fallTransform.setOrigin(new bullet.Bt.Vector3(0, 50, 0));
var centerOfMassOffsetFallTransform = new bullet.Bt.Transform();
centerOfMassOffsetFallTransform.setIdentity();
var fallMotionState = new bullet.Bt.DefaultMotionState(fallTransform, centerOfMassOffsetFallTransform);

var fallInertia = new bullet.Bt.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
// fallShape.calculateLocalInertia(1, fallInertia);
var fallRigidBodyCI = new bullet.Bt.RigidBodyConstructionInfo(1, fallMotionState, fallShape, fallInertia);
var fallRigidBody = new bullet.Bt.RigidBody(fallRigidBodyCI);
dynamicsWorld.addRigidBody(fallRigidBody);

for (i in 0...3000) {
    dynamicsWorld.stepSimulation(1 / 60);

    var trans = new bullet.Bt.Transform();
    var m = fallRigidBody.getMotionState();
    m.getWorldTransform(trans);
    trace(trans.getOrigin().y());
    trans.delete();
}
```

It's a haxe port for Bullet3, but I think all components and the concept/logic remains the same as in c++. The idea is that the `fallShape` should bounce against the `groundShape`. But it doesn't. When printing the `trans.getOrigin().y()` it goes it to negative numbers. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Setting mass for static ground to 0

`var groundRigidBodyCI = new bullet.Bt.RigidBodyConstructionInfo(0.0, groundMotionState, cast groundShape, new bullet.Bt.Vector3(0, 0, 0));`

and enabling `fallShape.calculateLocalInertia(1, fallInertia);`

worked for me!